# Minizinc "cannot determine lower bound" for float

Tags: floating-point, minizinc

I have a minizinc model where I have a distance matrix:

```
array[1..n, 1..n] of var float: dist;
```

Which will output the error `Error: Gecode: Float::linear: Number out of limits`. If I try to minimize the the matrix for example with `solve minimize sum(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j]);` (in reality the code is more complex).The lower bound is clear to me. No value in the distance matrix can be lower than zero. Formulating a constraint with the lowerbound will however not work:

```
constraint forall(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j] >= 0.0);
```

Making the domain smaller will work. But I can not say ahead of time what will be the upper bound of the domain (for the code bellow I just took a very big number, which might in certain cases be too small):

```
array[1..n, 1..n] of var 0.0..1000000.0: dist;
```

Is there a posibility to only define the lower bound?

I use Minizinc 2.2.1 with geocode 6.0.1.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you are getting? I ran the model:

    `int: n = 3;
    array[1..n, 1..n] of var float: dist;
    constraint forall(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j] >= 0.0);
    solve satisfy;`

with MiniZinc 2.2.1 (solving with Gecode) and got a result without an error message.

Comment: Thank you @AndreaRendl-Pitrey I have clarified the question. I simplified my example too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the `Error: Gecode: Float::linear: Number out of limits` because Gecode (and any other CP solver) will need an upper and lower bound for every variable. In your objective you are summing over variables that each ranges from `0.0..1000000.0`. Internally, MiniZinc creates a variable for this sum expression, and the domain of this variable exceeds Gecode's internal bounds.

So I see two solutions for solving this issue:

1) Create the objective variable yourself and set an upper bound for it. The following model works for me on MiniZinc 2.2.1 and Gecode 6.0.1:

```
int: n = 3;
array[1..n, 1..n] of var 0.0..100000.0: dist; 
% a new variable for the objective term with a lower and upper bound
var 0.0..1000000.0: total_distance;  

constraint forall(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j] >= 0.0);

constraint    % set the objective term
   total_distance = sum(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j]);

solve minimize total_distance;
```

2) Don't use a CP solver, but use a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) solver. They can deal with variables that have infinite bounds. MiniZinc comes with the MIP solver CBC, and it solves the following MiniZinc model without problems:

```
int: n = 3;
array[1..n, 1..n] of var float: dist;

constraint forall(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j] >= 0.0);

solve minimize sum(i,j in 1..n)(dist[i,j]);
```